# Compositing using glow nodes - blocky results / poor AA

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

When I attempt to create a glow in the compositor I always end up with a blocky, non-antialiased result. What am I doing wrong? I attach the composite render, the non-composite render and my node group. Thank you.

[image: example image and node group]

Comment: Try using the normal Gaussian blur mode instead of the Fast Gaussian, for the blur node.

Comment: Switch color depth to 16-bit that might help

Comment: Cycles or Blender Internal. The material index layer is unusable with Cycles and in BI you need to turn on *Full Sample AA* to get nice edges.

Comment: Thanks everyone, changing to 16-bit didn't help - gaussian blur as opposed to fast gaussian helped a bit overall but it didn't improve the IndexMA pass which is where the blockiness is coming from. So sadly, as I am using Cycles, Jaroslav's answer seems to be right one which is a pain as there may be no fix. Thank you again everyone.